# How to pass data from foreach loop to another page by clicking on a button in blazor

Tags: blazor

I want to pass `customer.Id` from the current customer in foreach loop to another page by clicking the button Add issue.

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var customer in customers)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@customer.Id / @customer.LastName / @customer.Email</td>
            <RadzenButton Text="Add issue" ButtonStyle="Radzen.ButtonStyle.Secondary" Click="@GoToCustomerIssue"/>
            <RadzenButton Text="Edit" ButtonStyle="Radzen.ButtonStyle.Secondary" />
            <RadzenButton Text="Delete" ButtonStyle="Radzen.ButtonStyle.Secondary" />
        </tr>       
    }
</tbody>
```

```
public int GoToCustomerIssue()
{
    NavManager.NavigateTo($"/customerissue/{}")
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to navigate, rather than to use a Component?  I very rarely need to actually navigate to a new page.

Comment: I need a new page to create comments and show the list of comments of the issue.

Comment: How do you think if you want to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass lambdas to event handlers.  So your line:

```
<RadzenButton Text="Add issue" ButtonStyle="Radzen.ButtonStyle.Secondary" Click="@GoToCustomerIssue"/>
```

Can be easily modified to a lambda:

```
<RadzenButton Text="Add issue" ButtonStyle="Radzen.ButtonStyle.Secondary" Click="() => GoToCustomerIssue(customer.Id)" />
```

This allows you to capture the local context (the `customer`) and pass what you need to your event handler.  Obviously, your event handler would need to be modified to accept that argument:

```
public int GoToCustomerIssue(int customerId)
{
    NavManager.NavigateTo($"/customerissue/{customerId}")
}
```

All that said, it'd probably be more idiomatic to not use an event handler at all, and simply construct your URL to incorporate the `id` directly, but I don't think `RadzenButton` supports that concept.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of navigating, you can use a boolean value to display your customerissue logic.

**This Page**

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var customer in customers)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@customer.Id / @customer.LastName / @customer.Email</td>
            <RadzenButton Text="Add issue" ButtonStyle="Radzen.ButtonStyle.Secondary" Click="()=>GoToCustomerIssue(customer)"/>
            <RadzenButton Text="Edit" ButtonStyle="Radzen.ButtonStyle.Secondary" />
            <RadzenButton Text="Delete" ButtonStyle="Radzen.ButtonStyle.Secondary" />
        </tr>       
    }
</tbody>
@if (SelectedCustomer is not null){
     <CustomerIssue Customer=SelectedCustomer />
}

@code {
    List<customer> customers {get; set;} // or whatever your customer class is called
    customer SelectedCustomer {get; set;}

    GoToCustomerIssue(customer clickedCustomer){
      SelectedCustomer = clickedCustomer;
    }
}
```

Then change your customerissue page to a Component, **CustomerIssue.razor** using your customer class instead of just an ID:

```
@code{
    [Parameter]
    public customer Customer {get; set;}
}
```

This way, you will have already have access to that whole customer class (ID, LastName, Email, etc.), instead of just the ID, and you will not have to navigate to a new page.  Don't worry, the browser will not even begin to load the customerissue page until you've selected a customer.